# Rails - Redirecting after AJAX POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, stripe-payments

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be incredibly simple - subscribe a user to a Stripe subscription plan and redirect them to the root path upon success. Nothing fancy.

I have 3 plans, which I define in my Rails controller, and loop through each plan to create a Stripe handler for each. The handlers in my view look like this:

```
handlers["#{count}"] = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "#{ENV['stripe_publishable_key']}",
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
        $.ajax({
            url: `/subscriptions`,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                "stripeToken": token.id,
                "stripeEmail": token.email,
                "stripe_price": "#{plan[:stripe_price]}",
                "plan": "#{plan[:name]}",
                "description": "Subscription to #{plan[:name].capitalize} plan"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: `window.location = '/'`
        });
    }
});
```

The success callback is something I added recently, just to try to get it to redirect somewhere upon success. Didn't work...

The event listener:

```
document.getElementById("subscriptionButton-#{count}").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handlers["#{count}"].open({
        name: "#{plan[:name].capitalize} plan",
        description: "Sign up for #{plan[:name].capitalize} plan",
        email: "#{current_user.email}",
        amount: "#{plan[:stripe_price]}"
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Everything works perfectly in terms of sending the data to my subscriptions controller and the I can successfully create the subscriptions on Stripe. All I need to do is redirect the user.

The block I'm using in my controller is:

```
flash[:success] = "Successfully signed up"
puts "Got here"
respond_to do |format|
    puts request.format
    format.js { render js: "window.location = '#{root_path}';" }
end
```

The `request.format` returns `application/json`. I thought it would return js, since it's responding to an AJAX request. Is this what's screwing up the redirect? If so, how does one go about redirect when the format is json? Or am I missing something else completely?

Comment: Haha thank you, Rockwell Rice. I didn't know this was a thing... Works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the data type javascript

```
handlers["#{count}"] = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: "#{ENV['stripe_publishable_key']}",
locale: 'auto',
token: function(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/subscriptions`,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            "stripeToken": token.id,
            "stripeEmail": token.email,
            "stripe_price": "#{plan[:stripe_price]}",
            "plan": "#{plan[:name]}",
            "description": "Subscription to #{plan[:name].capitalize} plan"
        },
        dataType: 'script', <--- right here
        success: `window.location = '/'`
    });
  }
});
```