# in Rails, render Json how to redirect conditionaly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, redirect, rendering

In my app, i've got a Meeting and a Contact model.
I've setup a jquery function with selectize which allows me to create a new contact directly in my meeting/new form.
To do so, I use a POST request in ajax, with render json for my create method in contacts_controller.rb :

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  @user = current_user
  @contact.user = @user

  if @contact.save!
    render json: @contact, except: :avatar
  else
  render json: { errors: @contact.errors.full_message }
  end
end
```

This behavior is perfect in my meeting/create method, because it allows me to create a new contact with a modal and get the callback of my function in my form to display the new contact name.
Here is my meeting/new view:

```
*view : meeting/new*

<%= simple_form_for(@meeting) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :start_date %>
  <%= f.input :end_date %>
  <%= f.association :contact, collection: Contact.all.pluck(:fullname, :id), input_html: { class: "select-contact" } %>

  <%= f.submit 'Enregistrer un nouvel rendez-vous', class:'btn btn-secondary' %>
<% end %>

<div class="modal fade contact-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Ajouter un contact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= simple_form_for Contact.new, remote: true do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :first_name %>
          <%= f.input :last_name %>
          <%= f.input :fullname %>

          <%= f.submit 'Ajouter un nouveau contact', class:'btn btn-primary' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that i want also to create a new contact via my contact/new view. But after creating this contact, i would redirect to my index view.

```
*view : contact/new*

<%= simple_form_for [ @user, @contact ] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :avatar, as: :file %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :fullname %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :phone_number %>
  <%= f.input :tag_list %>
  <%= f.input :birthdate, as: :string, type: :text, input_html: {class: "datepicker", id: "birthdate"} %>
<%# raise %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Due to my create method in contact controller, it triggers a render json when my contact is save, but there is not redirection

When i create a new contact through my meeting/new view, I would render json with no redirection. While when i create a new contact in contact/new view, i would redirect to my contacts/index view after creating.
In both cases, I need to Post an ajax request to store some datas.

Is anyone knows how i can do that ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Right. rails `remote: true` form functionality doesnt allow listening to HTTP status code.
You have to use JavaScript to do that.

Your Question is simila to this [rails-redirecting-after-ajax-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702203/rails-redirecting-after-ajax-post)

If you want help writing JavaScript for that let me know.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your reply.

I tried what you adviced. But in fact, i think my case is a bit more complicated. 
In bot cases : create a contact via contact form and contact view, and create a contact via meeting form and view, i need to send a ajax request.

But in first case (create contact via contact form and contact view) i would redirect to my contacts (index method in contact controller), whereas in 2nd case (create a contact via meeting form and view) i would redirect to my meetings (index method in meeting controller).

Comment: here is my JS :

  $("#new_contact").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(response) {
        window.location = '/meetings';
        console.log(response);
        selectizeCallback({
          value: response.id,
          text: response.fullname
        });
        $(".contact-modal").modal('toggle');
        // selectizeCallback = null;

      }
    });
  });